# react router, multiple components warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As per https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#components-1, I'm specifying multiple components in my routes, and I'm getting warnings. It seems to work fine, but I like to heed warnings.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`.
```

I saw several other questions on this warning and the answer is usually to check spelling. I don't think it's a spelling issue.

```
<Route path="search" component={Search} />
<Route path="search2" component={{main:Search}} />
```

The first gets no warning but the second one does (as do routes where I'm actually specifying multiple components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`component` != `components`

Multiple components are provided via the `components` property, not the singular `component`:

```
// # component; singular
<Route path="/" component={App}>  # component; singular

  // # components; plural
  <Route path="groups" components={{main: Groups, sidebar: GroupsSidebar}} />
```

Comment: Whoops! Missed the `s`. Thanks! *blushing*